# Find the Domain of the Function g such that gf and g inverse exists.

Tags: functions, inverse-function

The functions $f$ and $g$ are defined as follows:

$$f(x)=(2e^x-1)^2+2, x\in\mathbb R$$
$$g(x)=(x-1)^2-1, x\ge k$$

Find the range of values of $k$ such that both functions $gf$ and $g^{-1}$ exists.

I tried to do this question using this method:

Range of $f=[2,\infty)$

Range of $g=[1,\infty)$

In order for the function $gf$ to exist, The Range of $f\subseteq$ Domain of $g$

Therefore $k\le2$ for $gf$ to exist.

For $g^{-1}$ to exist, $k\le1$ or $k\ge1$ as the minium point of $g$ is $(1,-1)$ (The function $g$ needs to be a one-one function for its inverse to exist.)

Therefore, for both functions to exist, The domain of $g$ has to be $(k\le2) \land (k\le1) \iff (k\le1)$ OR $1\le k\le2$

Therefore the domain of $g$ can be $(-\infty, 1]$ or $[1,2]$

Both seem to be the correct answer but both of them at the same time contradicts the question as what they have written is $x\ge k$

Will appreciate it if someone can check if my answer is correct. If the answer is not correct, please do point out my mistakes in solving this question, thank you!

Comment: I made some edits as I have found out some of my mistakes, seems like both domains can be accepted as solutions.

Comment: Range of $g$ is $[-1,\infty]$

Comment: Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain of $g$ is $[k,\infty)$. In order of $g^{-1}$ to exist, $k$ can not be less than $1$. Because if $k<1$, the domain of $g$ would contain some open interval around the minimum at $x=1$, and hence it would not have inverse.

The existence of $gf$ implies $k\le 2$, as you have found properly.

Then, the conditions for $k$ are $k\ge 1$ and $k\le 2$. That is, if $1\le k\le 2$, both conditions are satisfied.

Don't mix it up with the domain of $g$. The domain of $g$ **is not** the set of possible values for $k$.

Comment: If $k\ge 2$, would that mean that $gf$ will not exist? Because the Range of $f$ is $[2, \infty)$

Comment: Sorry, I confused the sign. Fixed.

Comment: I think the question is pretty confusing because they stated to find the range of values of $k$, but essentially am I safe to say that this question just wants me to find the Domain of $g$?

This is because $g^{-1}$ can exist if its domain is either $(-\infty, 1]$ or $[1, \infty)$

Comment: Oh right, looks like I got it, thanks for the help!